# Does *BSD have the ability to encrypt a system partition with full disk encryption?

Tags: freebsd, encryption, openbsd, disk-encryption, netbsd

Does FreeBSD, NetBSD, or OpenBSD have an encryption feature like Linux's dm-crypt?
And will it work for a system partition?

Comment: I wrote a short article about [how to install OpenBSD fully encrypted on GPT with EFI boot](https://www.sugioarto.com/articles/2016/05/04/openbsd-efi-gpt-fde.html) some time ago.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what it is on NetBSD?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, this is documented in the handbook:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disks-encrypting.html

And although `gbde` is mentioned first, `geli` is generally more recommended. The installer actually will even help you set this up, there's a prompt for it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenBSD has [softraid(4)](https://man.openbsd.org/softraid.4), which allows you to use an encrypting discipline on a block device. Setting up disk encryption is not supported by the installer (as of September 2020), but can be configured by hand during an operating system installation. OpenBSD [FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html) has a section dedicated to [Full Disk Encryption](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraidFDE) which can be used as a reference for setting up disk or partition encryption.

Answer (score 2):

NetBSD can indeed be run with an encrypted root filesystem, via a kernel module called `cdgroot` (though it still needs an unencrypted partition to boot from).

See the following for some comments on the concept and configuration:

[NetBSD Root Filesystem Encryption](https://wiki.netbsd.org/security/cgdroot/)